# Probabilistic union

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Could somebody shed some light into the following Problem: the probability that property $a$ occures is $5\%$ and that property $b$ occures is $20\%$. There are though objects which share the both property ($a$ and $b$ at the same time). What is the probability that an event with both properties can occur? The answer should be $24\%$. I don't understand why!

Can somebody help me understand that? I was trying by using the formula concerning not mutually exclusive events...but I don't know how to calculate the probabilistic union in order to calculate the probability of the intersection. Am I wrong? Thanks.

Comment: $P(A \cup B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A \cap B)$. $A \cup B$ is the event "$A$ or $B$", and $A \cap B$ is "$A$ and $B$".

Comment: @M.Vinay hrm, how do you calculate $P(A \cup B)$ from the info above? Or am I understanding the problem wrong and you're not trying to find $P(A \cap B)$?

Comment: Actually, something is missing here. What is the probability that at least one of $A$ or $B$ occurs?

Answer (score 2):

If events $A$ and $B$ have probabilities $0.05$ and $0.2$, then it *cannot*
be the case that $P(A\cap B)$, the
probability that *both* events occur is $0.24$; $P(A\cap B)$ is no larger than
$\min(P(A), P(B)) = 0.05$.

I would suspect that what you are being asked for is 
$P(A\cup B)$, the
probability that *at least one of these events* occurs,
and not $P(A\cap B)$, the probability that *both* of these events
occur.  I also suspect *that what you have been told but are
not telling us* (or maybe the writer of the problem failed to include it
in the problem statement)
is that events $A$ and $B$ are *independent*. If $A$ and $B$ are given
(or assumed) to be independent, then
$$\begin{align}
P(A\cup B) &= P(A) + P(B) - P(A\cap B) &{\scriptstyle{\text{always true; independence not needed}}}\\
&= P(A) + P(B) - P(A)P(B)
&{\scriptstyle{\text{because}~ A~\text{and}~B~\text{are independent events}}}\\
&= 0.05 + 0.2 - 0.05\times 0,2\\
&= 0.24
\end{align}$$

Comment: p(A) alone is 5%, p(B) alone 20 %.There are individuals who by chance present both diseases(A and B are independent ).Estimate the probability of the individuals with both diseases. My answer would be 0,05 X 0,2 = 0,01 which is 1 %.One reads''with both disease A and disease B would be hospitalized at a combined rate that takes into account the rate for disease A alone, 5% and that of disease B alone, 20%. The probabilistic union of these two rates produces a hospitalization rate of 24% ''But probalistic union means the probability to find at least A or B and not A and B. Please for comment.